# How to manage project using tortoise svn?

Tags: tortoisesvn

### My Goal

I want to modify wordpress project as per my needs. I also want to record the `code difference` i made in the project. That is my goal.

### This is what i done so far

- I installed recent version of [tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html).
- I'm using windows 7    and i have installed wampserver too
- I created a folder called    `wordpress` in `C:/wamp/www`
- So    `C:/wamp/www/wordporess` is now the    absolute path of my
  wordpress    directory. I can able to access it via
  http://localhost/wordpress
- I right clicked on the `wordpress` directory and created checkout
  using this repository url `http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/`
- Everything successful so far. I'm so confused about the next step

When i right click `wordpress` and open repository browser it actually list everything from `http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/`  But i need an environment like trunk,tags,branches in my local directory.   I tried by creating checkout on a empty directory(test) by applying url like http://localhost/test but i see some error like `redirect cycle detected for url http://localhost/test`

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you need to do the checkout from the root and not from the trunk

like `http://core.svn.wordpress.org`

Advise you to read  word press documentation for detail how they are maintaining there structure and other things.

1. [Wordpress-Using_Subversion](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Subversion)
2. [Updating_WordPress_with_Subversion](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing/Updating_WordPress_with_Subversion)

Answer (score 2):

I'm running into the same problem as well.

After some experiments I think it should be caused by following procedure:

( if `test` is a directory under your web root )

1. svn client remove the trailing slash for some reason. so for example if you type `svn list http://localhost/test/` then the actual request url will be `http://localhost/test` ( no trailing slash! ).
2. The http server receive this request and found that `test` is not file but a directory. so it will send a redirect response to tell client to visit `http://localhost/test/` ( has slash) .
3. the svn client go on step 1 so that finally causing infinite redirect loop....

You can try another **non-exist directory** like 'nonexist' or a **file** file to test as well which will returen "Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://localhost/nonexist' ..."

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed on the server side in Apache by setting `DocumentRoot` to something other than the path containing the SVN repositories (preferably an empty directory).